# Print a PDF via an iframe in Chrome/Firefox/IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, pdf, iframe

I want to trigger the print of a PDF file which I load in and iframe.

After looking around, I came up with the following bit

```
<iframe name="pdfname" id="pdfid"></iframe>

<button id="printbtn">Print</button>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#pdfid").load(function() {
            window.frames["pdfname"].focus();
            window.frames["pdfname"].print();
        });

        $("#printbtn").click(function () {
            $("#pdfid").attr("src", '@Url.Action("PdfTest", "Home")');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome.

In Firefox, I get the following error (I read somewhere it was a bug that was supposed to be fixed in version 21, but it wasn't)

**Permission denied to access property 'print'**

In Internet Explorer 10 and 9, I get the following error

**Invalid calling object**

which seems to point to the PDF generated by my MVC action.

I've seen numerous posts with problems similar to mine, yet haven't come across a working solution so far.

What I would really want to know is how RADPDF managed to get this working in every browser

[Click the print button on this page](http://www.radpdf.com/demo/custom-interface/)

I know this can be done, I need help from you brains out there!

Cheers

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out? Care to share?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following, might work in all browsers. ( I have tested with IE8 and chrome only )

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print 
    {
        .dontprint{display:none} 
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printIframePdf(){
        window.frames["printf"].focus();
        try {
            window.frames["printf"].print();
        }
        catch(e){
            window.print();
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    function printObjectPdf() {
        try{            
            document.getElementById('idPdf').Print();
        }
        catch(e){
            printIframePdf();
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    function idPdf_onreadystatechange() {
        if (idPdf.readyState === 4)
            setTimeout(printObjectPdf, 1000);
    }
</script>
<div class="dontprint" >
    <form><input type="button" onClick="printObjectPdf()" class="btn" value="Print"/></form>
</div>

<iframe id="printf" name="printf" src="http://pdfUrl.pdf" frameborder="0" width="440" height="580" style="width: 440px; height: 580px;display: none;"></iframe>
<object id="idPdf" onreadystatechange="idPdf_onreadystatechange()"
    width="440" height="580" style="width: 440px; height: 580px;" type="application/pdf"
    data="http://pdfUrl.pdf">
    <embed src="http://pdfUrl.pdf" width="440" height="580" style="width: 440px; height: 580px;" type="application/pdf">
    </embed>
    <span>PDF plugin is not available.</span>
</object>
```