# How to use JavaScript to open and print PDF directly without preview it?

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, cross-browser

I have the file print.htm deployed to localhost, this solution only work in Chrome, do not work in IE and FF.

In Chrome, it pops up this dialog nicely:[image: Print in Chrome]

In FF and IE, nothing happens.

I heard about PDF.js but would not want it if there is a native solution.
Is there someone who managed to print PDF directly in FF/IE ?

Here are my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>MDN Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function closePrint () {
  document.body.removeChild(this.__container__);
}

function setPrint () {
  this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;
  this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.onafterprint = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.focus(); // Required for IE
  console.log(this.contentWindow);  
  this.contentWindow.print();
}

function printPage (sURL) {
  var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  oHiddFrame.onload = setPrint;
  oHiddFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";
  oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
  oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
  oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
  oHiddFrame.src = sURL;
  document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="idPrint1" onclick="printPage('file.pdf')">Load and Print </button>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone who downvote, points out what is the reason. For e.g: why is it considered too broad ? It's a very specific issue right: open a PDF file and print it via JavaScript.

Comment: is this helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611925/print-a-pdf-via-an-iframe-in-chrome-firefox-ie

Comment: @krnekires: sorry with Chrome 38 and Firefox 33, it did not work.