# How to print a iframe content using javascript in firefox?

Tags: jsp

how to print iframe content.I mean pdf content.Its working in crome browser but not working in firefox.I want to print iframe content only.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611925/print-a-pdf-via-an-iframe-in-chrome-firefox-ie

Comment: In Firefox, I get the following error (I read somewhere it was a bug that was supposed to be fixed in version 21, but it wasn't)

Permission denied to access property 'print'