# Print PDF from embed element in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a web page with PDF and I need to open a print preview dialog from javascript in Chrome browser. Basically I need to do like a click on print button in Chrome's PDF viewer. PDF is displayed in embed element.

In IE I just call print method of the embed element and it works fine, but apparently in Chrome there is no such method...

```
<embed id="previewDoc" src="https://blog.mozilla.org/security/files/2015/05/HTTPS-FAQ.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="750px" height="750px"></embed>
```

Is it possible at all to do that? 
I found an answer to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/27047724/1157249, but the only suggestion it has is to embed some action into PDF itself...

Comment: Assuming it's the same origin, you could use an iframe...

Comment: Joe DF, looks like you right... So far the only workaround that I found is using iframe   https://stackoverflow.com/a/20240762/1157249